# Optimize Django model save method for accessing to uploaded file path

Tags: python, django

in my Django application models I need to access to an ImageField, in the save() method, to extract some gps information and populate the other MyModel fields before I save the entire model instance.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    if self.image:
        # Todo: remove the double call of super(Photo, self).save() method by accessing the file before it will save
        super(Photo, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
        image_file = gpsimage.open(self.image.path)  #gpsimage.open needs a file path that I can have it only after I call super(Photo, self).save(....)
        ...
        ...
        ...
        # Final save call
        super(Photo, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

Is possible to access to a temp file (image) path, extract information from it, and than, if all fields are valid, save the entire model? 
Any other elegant solution?

My current app is a REST and admin app, so I wish to add this logic in a centric model.

Comment: Can we see what `gpsimage` is? If it's a field of the model, please include that line of code.

Comment: @sgarza62 gpsimage is a 3rd parties python module that extract gps information from an image.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the filepath from your custom save method like so: `self.myimg.name`, where `myimg` is the name of your field.

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
import os

def img_file_path(instance, filename):
    ''' Creates a filepath and name for an image file. '''
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    today = datetime.date.today()
    return os.path.join('imgs', '%s/%s/%s' % (today.year, today.month, today.day), filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    myimg = models.ImageField(upload_to = img_file_path)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        path_of_file = self.myimg.name

        # edit path_of_file, or whatever
        self.myimg.name = path_of_file.upper()

        super(MyModel, self).save()
```

If you take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L215), the filename is determined in the `__init__()` method, so it'll be accessible to you as soon as the object is created (before being saved and committed).

Comment: I'll test your solution, but at first look, the self.myimg.name will have the same value as self.myimage.path (in my code). My problem is that at save() call, the images hasn't been saved / copied to its self.myimage.path so, when I passed this value to a gpsimage.open() I receive a file not found error.

Comment: Substantially, I need to have a temp folder for uploaded file that are to be validating and only after this validation, are saved to destination folder (upload_to="path").

Comment: I've solved my problem by add to the gps parse module the in-memory image open method. With this, I don't need to save the image file to filesystem before it will parse from gps module.

Comment: @FabrizioA  Glad to hear you were able to solve your problem! So you're using PIL's `Image.open`; correct? Apologies, I thought you were looking to extract information from the filepath, not the temporary file itself. If you don't mind, I'll edit the question details to reflect this.

Comment: Hi @sgarza62, my problem was the request of remove the double call of super(Photo, self).save(...) needed to save the uploaded image to destinatiom path, and then open it to read the gps info from image. Give that, I needed a tip to save the image to a temp folder (without call the first super.save method), open this path, read the info and if all is correct, call the super.save method to copy the image to correct media folder. The solution of calling double super.save in my override save method generated double sql query to my db.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was to save two times. Here's my code:

```
 26     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
 27         super(GeoFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
 28         self.filetype = self.possible_type()
 29         if self.filetype == 'SHPZ':
 30             self.fileinfo = self.shpz_info()
 31             if 'srid' in self.fileinfo and not self.fileinfo['srid'] is None:
 32                 self.srid = self.fileinfo['srid']
 41         super(GeoFile, self).save()
```

Comment: Don't save with *args and **kwargs again because it will try to create a new object and will violate the unique key constraint.